# How do you know if something was designed mobile first?

Tags: website-design, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-web

Now I read lot of articles about mobile first design, and I understood that it's the way of design for the mobile first.

My question is, how do we know a website is designed with a mobile first -approach or not? And what are the benefits of mobile first compared to a responsive design?

Comment: Really, you can't. Mobile First is a concious decision by the UX designers et al. when initially planning the project to ensure it will be as usable and provide as good a UX as possible on a Mobile as well as on desktop. If a site works well on all devices you look at it on then that might be a clue, but really it's like asking "How can you tell if a website was developed using Agile methodology"; you can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, mobile first and responsive don't present an either / or choice.

Mobile **first is a methodology** that you use to approach your design, where you constrain yourself to the limits of mobile.  After working that out, it is much easier to modify that design for pc - usually with a better, more focused end product.

**Responsive design is a behaviour** whereby your layout changes depending on some properties of the device viewing it.

There is nothing stopping a design which was created with a mobile first methodology from being a responsive design at all.  In fact I would often recommend that it is.

In terms of recognising a mobile first design, there is no clear way.  It is just a methodology for designing that many people find helpful. Usually a mobile first design is more focused and clear on what it is achieving, but you get poor examples of mobile first and good examples of pc first design.  A lot depends on the team designing it in the first place.

Mobile first comparison:

[image]

Responsive Design illustration:
[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. But I would replace 'web first design' with 'large screen design' or 'pc design' or something more appropriate as mobile web is still the web :)

Comment: @Kayo good point.  I'll change it.

Comment: @JohnGB I found another article describes about my question. What do you think ?

http://www.uie.com/articles/mobile_first_rwd/

Comment: @SurjithSM Interesting article.